# make unordered list scrollable

Tags: html, css

I want to make the unordered list scrollable the main list Data Source Connections should be at same place only the sub ul li elements should be scrollable

I have added **overflow:scroll** property to ul tag still the scrolling is not active

what can be the issue?

Is there any other CSS property to be included?

```css
.whole-dbsource {
  height: 100%;
}

.db-pagerow {
  margin-left: 12%;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 80%;
}

.source-container {
  height: 300px; /* ED: Changed to see the dropdown */
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

h5 {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

h5.submenu-open {
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #28be9a;
}

ul.src-main-menu {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 12px;
}

ul.src-main-menu .src-main-sub {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

ul.src-main-menu li.src-main-sub {
  padding: 1px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

ul.src-main-menu li ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  overflow:scroll;
  max-height: 1000px;
  /*fallback for FireFox */
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

ul.src-main-menu li ul i {
  display: inline-block;
}

.src-main-sub ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding:0 5px;
}

.src-main-sub ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul.src-main-menu li ul.open {
  display: block;
}

ul.src-main-menu .src-main-sub i {
  transition: all 0.5s;
   
}
ul.src-main-menu .src-main-sub i.ion-chevron-down {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  position: static;
  left: 0;
}

ul.src-main-menu li i.closed {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
}

ul.src-main-menu li i.open {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css"/>

<div class="container-fluid whole-dbsource">
  <div class="row db-pagerow">
    <div class="col-sm-7 source-container">
      <ul class="src-main-menu">
        <li class="src-main-sub">
          <h5 class="src-sub-menu">Data Source Connections<i class="ion-chevron-down closed float-right"></i></h5>
          <ul class="closed">
            <li><span class='d-block'>Oracle 12c</span><i class="ion-edit d-block mt-2"></i></li>
            <li><span class='d-block'>PostgresSQL</span><i class="ion-edit d-block mt-2"></i></li>
            <li><span class='d-block'>MySql</span><i class="ion-edit d-block mt-2"></i></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: height + overflow: scroll

Comment: @pavel how do i need to include this property and where?

Answer (score 0):

you fixed the height on 100% just give height in px. And remember one thing scroll on max-height come after its limit in your code the scroll comes after 1000px, hope it will help

```
 ul.src-main-menu li ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  overflow:scroll;
  /*max-height: 1000px;*/
  /*fallback for FireFox */
  height: 100px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Comment: still the background remains same with no scroll.background will be applied to entire ul height